# Proof that a continuous function on a bounded and closed domain is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, riemann-integration, multiple-integral

Let $$f: D \subset \mathbf{R}^{2} \to \mathbf{R} $$ a continuous function and $ D $ a bounded and closed domain. Prove that f is integrable.

I have been reviewing my exercises and this is one I cannot get a grip on. I am trying to enforce uniform continuity by taking  $$|(x,y) - (x_{0},y_{0})| < \epsilon \\ \iff |f(x,y) - f(x_{0},y_{0})| < \delta$$

But I have no clue as to how to continue. For functions of one dimension, the next step is to assume a partition $(I_{n})$ a finite partition of $[a,b]$ such that its diameter is less than $\delta$ and so on...

I have no idea how to transform that in two dimensions using squares. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for that, but my question is about two dimensions of the proof. I already knew the one dimensional proof :)

Comment: What do you mean by integrable? Do you mean $\int_D |f| < \infty$?

Comment: Riemann integrable.

Comment: How do you define $f$ on $D^c$? The tags say Lebesgue integral, you might wan tto update.

Comment: you should change the tag from Lebesgue-integral to Riemann in that case

Comment: Yup, sorry mate.

Comment: How do you define $f$ on the complement of $D$ and how do you know that the boundary of $D$ has measure zero?

Comment: Sorry mate, but I don't think I have to prove this using measures. It's Calc IV, and from what I can tell I need to use uniform continuity on two-dimensions. Sadly, this I cannot yet do.

Comment: Well, the Riemann integral is defined on a rectangle, so you need to know the value of $f$ for points not in $D$. There is no way around it.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not get you. So far, what I can see is this:

Bounded + Closed + Continuity = Uniform Continuity (that's Topology 101). 
Using the definition of U.C. I must go on to prove using Low and Upper Darboux Sums that f is integrable.

Comment: Are you allowed to use compactness?

Comment: $f$ is only defined on $D$. What does it mean to integrate $f$ on $D$? All definitions I have seen of the Riemann integral are for functions defined on a rectangle (or the appropriate product of intervals in higher dimensions). Typically this is done by extending $f$ to be zero outside $D$. However, then $D$ needs to be suitably 'nice' so the integral exists.

Comment: If $D$ was a compact rectangle we would not be having this discussion.